# Logback warning reconfiguration on change cannot be done

Tags: java, logback, logback-classic, logstash-logback-encoder

I have a warning already for quite a long time in one of my Java/ kotlin projects with logback and wanted to know if there is a way to solve it. The project uses logback in combination with Jersey with the following logback dependencies:

```
implementation("org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:2.0.12")
implementation("org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.0.12")
implementation("org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:2.0.12")
implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4")
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.14")
```

This is the full logback message I get when I startup the container:

```
10:49:56,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Removing shutdownHook Thread[Logback shutdown hook [default],5,RMI Runtime]
10:49:56,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - ShutdownHook removal result: true
10:49:55,919 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
10:49:55,921 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [jsonConsoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
10:49:55,922 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@6f016ee - End of configuration.
10:49:55,923 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1cde49b4 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
10:49:55,923 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure() call lasted 540 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=DO_NOT_INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
10:49:56,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Removing shutdownHook Thread[Logback shutdown hook [default],5,RMI Runtime]
10:49:56,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - ShutdownHook removal result: true
10:49:56,213 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Due to missing top level configuration file, reconfiguration on change (configuration file scanning) cannot be done.
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ShutdownHookModelHandler - About to instantiate shutdown hook of type [ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DefaultShutdownHook]
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ShutdownHookModelHandler - Registering shutdown hook with JVM runtime.
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [jsonConsoleAppender]
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [jsonConsoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@31b26160 - End of configuration.
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@46ce5328 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
10:49:55,374 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - This is logback-classic version 1.4.14
10:49:55,377 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - No custom configurators were discovered as a service.
10:49:55,377 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
10:49:55,379 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
10:49:55,379 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.scmo]
10:49:55,380 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.scmo]
10:49:55,382 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 1 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
10:49:55,382 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
10:49:55,383 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
10:49:55,384 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
10:49:55,384 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projects/<apiName>/build/libs/exploded/<apiName>-1.0.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
10:49:55,523 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Registering a new ReconfigureOnChangeTask ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1707385795522)
10:49:55,523 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Will scan for changes in [file:/C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projects/<apiName>/build/libs/exploded/<apiName>-1.0.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] 
10:49:55,524 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 1 minutes
10:49:55,527 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ShutdownHookModelHandler - About to instantiate shutdown hook of type [ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DefaultShutdownHook]
10:49:55,527 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ShutdownHookModelHandler - Registering shutdown hook with JVM runtime.
10:49:55,529 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [jsonConsoleAppender]
10:49:55,529 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:49:55,919 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
10:49:55,921 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [jsonConsoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
10:49:55,922 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@6f016ee - End of configuration.
10:49:55,923 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1cde49b4 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
10:49:55,923 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@3974b1fd - ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure() call lasted 540 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=DO_NOT_INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
10:49:56,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Removing shutdownHook Thread[Logback shutdown hook [default],5,RMI Runtime]
10:49:56,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - ShutdownHook removal result: true
10:49:56,213 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Due to missing top level configuration file, reconfiguration on change (configuration file scanning) cannot be done.
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ShutdownHookModelHandler - About to instantiate shutdown hook of type [ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DefaultShutdownHook]
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ShutdownHookModelHandler - Registering shutdown hook with JVM runtime.
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [jsonConsoleAppender]
10:49:56,213 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [jsonConsoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@31b26160 - End of configuration.
10:49:56,217 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@46ce5328 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

And this is my logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DefaultShutdownHook"/>

    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <customFields>{"api_name":"sectionmonitoring","platform":"ecs"}</customFields>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Hope that someone can point me in the right direction to solve this warning.

Comment: Can you set the `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml` property and check if the warning disappears?

Comment: Another question, do you need "Automatically reloading configuration file upon modification" https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/the-logback-manual/content/en/chapter-3-configuration/configuration-in-logback/automatically-reloading-configuration-file-upon-modification.html#automatically-reloading-configuration-file-upon-modification ?